# What certificate providers are sure to work for code signing a Java ME midp application?

Tags: java-me, certificate, code-signing

We've developed a Java ME MIDP application and are targeting the most popular Nokia, Samsung and LG phones.

Are there any recommendations to which certificate provider i should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading some posts on various fora, following is my conclusion:

- You can't really be sure the certificate authority you signed your application with will be installed on the device you developed for.
- But the more popular companies like Verisign or Thawte do have a good chance being installed on many devices.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the popular companies ,Thawte,Verising,GeoTrust,Global Trust,etc